# How can I set the Interval of a performance protocol under 1 second with Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, performance-monitoring

I want to determine the utilization of the NICs of our server, while very small videos are transferred.

The smallest interval which I can set in Performance Monitor is a second. Unfortunately, I need an Interval under 1 second.

Is there a way to make the interval less than one second?

If not, is there another monitoring tool for Windows Server 2003, which could solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ServerFault sysadmins ended up using Wireshark graphs](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/27/per-second-measurements-dont-cut-it/) when they needed sub-second bandwidth tracking. And this does indeed do the trick for network throughput. The problem with Windows is that the performance counters all use one second as the smallest monitoring interval, you simply *can't* get smaller then that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Windows Performance Toolkit to take a network-focused ETL trace, and then examine that in XPerf.

The new Message Analyzer beta might also be useful for this type of thing.

(Also: what sort of thing do you need that can't be aggregated at the 1 second mark?)